# Problems with nVidia Optimus secondary GPU in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

Every time I try to run something in Optimus mode I get a message like this:

```
[  277.250055] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  277.250091] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

There are some problems about the bars over the opened windows. They have different colorful patterns, which are simply annoying.

Comment: Hey, when did this start happening, I am experiencing the EXACT same issue as from today

Comment: It started today. I reinstalled Ubuntu like 10 times this week, every time with a different graphic problem. There were many of them: black screens, no bars, no dash, low resolution etc. This time it is the lack of optimus.

Comment: I am suspecting it's an update sent today that has caused it, my guess is you performed an update? Also, which ppa do you use for your graphics card (nvidia)?

Comment: Maybe it's the update. I don't know. I reinstaled ubuntu today, and it was there. I used  ppa:bumblebee/stable and  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa and ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates.

Comment: I've 3.11.0-17-generic

Comment: Well I also used the xorg-edgers PPA, but cannot afford to reinstall due to work, but my theory is that there is a bug between their driver and compiz. The reason I think this is because I also have KDE with all the desktop eyecandy but no issue whatsoever. Also, I reset unity, and the fading effect works perfectly fine, something you wouldn't expect from broken drivers on their own. Therefore, I believe it will be connected with Compiz in some way. If I find out anything, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Bumblebee installed, enable the Universe and Multiverse repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and if it's enabled already go next:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

reboot
```

P.S. `ppa` for `bumblebee` instructed here from official Bumblebee Source and if you wish to use any unofficial or experimental ppas with the latest features bug fixes for example [ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) or [ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) look at the Launchpad for more details on those ppas.

```
"Cannot access secondary GPU" error:
```

In LTS 12.04.3, 13.04 and later, if your card seems to be inaccessible, i.e. [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected. you need to edit the `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` (or `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau` if using the `noveau` driver) and specify the correct `BusID` by following the instructions below. How to find out GPU run in terminal `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` check every detail. Then add it to `xorg.conf`:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --connected-monitor="CRT" --busid=nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info | grep BusID | sed 's/PCI BusID : PCI:/PCI:/'
```

You should rather manually add it as instructed above if the command won't work.

After you need to restart `X` (reboot works)

```
sudo xxxdm restart
```

`xxx` - your display manager

if it won't start run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` and then `sudo xxxdm start`

[Instructions Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Comment: How can I find out the correct BusID?

Comment: your `xorg.conf` file should look similar to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/251693/how-to-use-nvidia-xconfig-with-2-gpus-and-one-is-not-nvidia)

Comment: nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info returns that nvidia-xconfig is not founf

Comment: I have nVidia 331 installed

Comment: @Adi.Jal this commands and workout did work for me maybe you're missing something read this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) about Hybrid Graphics to understand it more how it works.